# sscanf php multiple words echo

Tags: php, echo, scanf, words

I would like assistance to get an output of the string after `var:` instead of just the first word. Is this possible, and what is the basics to doing so. Thanks.

```
<?php
$string = "var:Kids Choice Awards iOS Application. change sql.";
sscanf($string,"var:%s",$var);
// show types and values
var_dump($var);
echo "$var";
?>
```

//output----------

```
string 'Kids' (length=4)
Kids
```

//end Output-------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with "%[regex]" format

```
<?php

$string = "var:Kids Choice Awards iOS Application. change sql.";
sscanf($string,"var:%[^&]", $var);
// show types and values
var_dump($var);
echo "$var";
?>
```

Comment: your way works...Now I would like to get two vars out the same string like below...but outputs as still one variable. see below.

    <?php
    $string = "var:This is the text for var. date:Sept 15";
    sscanf($string,"var:%[^&] date:%[^&]", $var, $date);
    echo "$var.$date";
    ?>
    /*output: This is the text for var. date:Sept 15*/
    //"date:" shouldnt be outputted

any suggestions?

Comment: you need better spacer: $string = "var:This is the text for var.&date:Sept 15";
sscanf($string,"var:%[^&]&date:%[^&]", $var, $date);

Comment: hey...is there a way to get construct variables within a class? below is not working
$string = "<span class='display'>title:This is the title.&date:August 28, 2012</span>";
sscanf($string,"title:%[^&]&date:%[^&]", $title, $date);

Comment: hi, you should consider replace sscanf to actual regular expressions [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: thanks bud... got it working. check this site out for regExp of many languages. it may come in handy. http://txt2re.com/