# Wrong Results by Using sscanf in PHP

Tags: php, scanf

Here is the Code i'm running Results are wrong as they supposed to be!

```
$results = sscanf("Sept 30th, 2014 ", "%s , %s, %d");
print_r($results);
```

But Results i'm Getting

```
(
   [0] => Sept
   [1] => 
   [2] => 
)
```

Results supposed to be :

```
(
  [0] => Sept
  [1] => 30th
  [2] => 2014
)
```

What's Wrong am i doing ? how can i fix that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12435847/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many commas in your format argument; your incoming string only has one comma in it.  The placeholders in `sscanf()` are always greedy. The `%s` placeholder matches consecutive non-whitespace characters.  You can exclude commas from beening consumed by the placeholder by using a negated character class containing a comma.

```
$results = sscanf("Sept 30th, 2014 ", "%s %[^,], %d");
print_r($results);
```

gives you

```
Array ( [0] => Sept [1] => 30th [2] => 2014 )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's about the comma, remove it from the format:

```
$results = sscanf("Sept 30th, 2014 ", "%s %s %d");
```

this should return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sept
    [1] => 30th,
    [2] => 2014
)
```

If you don't want the comma in result, you can remove it from the first array with `str_replace` or something

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$results = sscanf(" Sept 30th, 2014 ", "%s  %s %d");
$results[1]=str_replace(',','',$results[1]);// this can be done for entire array also.
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the comma try this:

```
$results = sscanf("Sept 30th, 2014 ", "%s %s %d");
$results = str_replace(',', '',$results);
print_r($results);
```

output: `Array ( [0] => Sept [1] => 30th [2] => 2014 )`